# Obter posição de elemento clicado

Tags: javascript, array, ecmascript-6

Tenho uma lista com itens cadastrados e um dos atributos desse item é um botão de deletar aquela item.

Ao clicar no botão quero saber qual é a posição da linha clicada dentro da lista.

Ao saber a posição eu vou deletar do array o mesmo valor da `posição[i]`

```
removeLinha(element){
    //Aqui eu obtenho a 'tr' clicada
    let trash = element.parentNode.parentNode; 

    //Aqui eu removo;
    trash.parentNode.removeChild(trash);
}
```

Mas antes de remover preciso saber a posição da `<tr>` dentro de `<tbody>` para apagar no array também.

**OBS: O grande problema é que o método de adicionar uma nova linha no DOM ele varre um array de objetos e coloca no DOM, por isso preciso saber a posição da linha para sabe a posição dela no array e deletar também.**

Comment: na verdade o this esta vindo como argumento na chamada do metodo lá no HTML.

Comment: Estou usando uma classe controller, então se eu uso o this dentro dela, ela seleciona a própria classe...

Comment: "para apagar no array também" - qual array ? foi construido como ? Pode incluir tanto o array como o html onde é chamada a função `removeLinha` ?

Comment: o array é preenchido dinamicamente com um objetivo que gera um elemento: `<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>` entao cada item do meu array é uma linha da minha tabela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar o `.closest('tr')` para ir buscar a `tr` e depois o `.indexOf(`.

Por exemplo:

```js
function removeLinha(element) {
  const trash = element.closest('tr');
  const index = [...trash.parentNode.children].indexOf(trash);
  trash.parentNode.removeChild(trash);


  console.log('Index era:', index); // só para o exemplo
}
```

```css
tr td:last-of-type:hover { color: #e88; }
```

```html
<table id="codexpl">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td onclick="removeLinha(this)">Remove</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Coloumn</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td onclick="removeLinha(this)">Remove</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>is</td>
    <td>not equals</td>
    <td onclick="removeLinha(this)">Remove</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>the</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td onclick="removeLinha(this)">Remove</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td onclick="removeLinha(this)">Remove</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Com estes JS puros, você consegue a posição `index` da linha do botão clicado e elimina a linha.

### Usando `eventListener`:

```js
window.onload = escuta;

botoes = document.getElementsByClassName("apagar");
function escuta(){
  for(x=0;x<botoes.length;x++){
    // arranjo os listeners com os index das linhas
    (function(index){
      botoes[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
        removeLinha(index);
      });
    })(x);
  }
}
 
function removeLinha(element){ // element é o index da linha clicada
   console.log(element); // mostrar index da linha como exemplo
  //removo a linha
  botoes[element].closest('tr').outerHTML = '';
  // removo os listeners
  for(x=0;x<botoes.length;x++){
    objclone = botoes[x].cloneNode(true);
    botoes[x].parentNode.replaceChild(objclone, botoes[x]);
  }
  escuta();
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Linha 1</td>
      <td><input class="apagar" type="button" value="X" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Linha 2</td>
      <td><input class="apagar" type="button" value="X" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Linha 3</td>
      <td><input class="apagar" type="button" value="X" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Linha 4</td>
      <td><input class="apagar" type="button" value="X" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### Usando `onclick`:

```js
function removeLinha(element){
  var el = element.closest('tr');
  var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(el.parentNode.children, el);
  console.log(index); // mostrar posição da linha como exemplo
  //removo a linha
  el.outerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Linha 1</td>
      <td><input class="apagar" type="button" value="X" onclick="removeLinha(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Linha 2</td>
      <td><input class="apagar" type="button" value="X" onclick="removeLinha(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Linha 3</td>
      <td><input class="apagar" type="button" value="X" onclick="removeLinha(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Linha 4</td>
      <td><input class="apagar" type="button" value="X" onclick="removeLinha(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é usar o `rowIndex`, que pega a posição real do elemento no `DOM`, basta referencia-lo com this, exemplo.

```js
var arr = ['tr1','tr2'];

var tr = document.querySelectorAll("tr");

for(var i=0; i<tr.length; i++){
  tr[i].onclick = function(){ 
      index = this.rowIndex;
      if(arr[index]) arr.splice(index, 1);
      this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
      console.log('tr clicada, posição ' + index + ' / arr: ' + arr);
 }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="tr1">
    <td>teste</td>
    <td>teste1</td>
    <td>teste2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2">
    <td>teste3</td>
    <td>teste4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você selecione uma `tr` e depois clique em um botão para excluir.

Segue o exemplo(Usei jquery pois já estou acostumado com o código, mas é só adaptar a lógica):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tid = "";
  $('#sua_tabela tr').click(function(event) {
    tid = $(this).attr('id');
  });
  $("#del").click(function() {
    console.log(tid);
    if ($('#' + tid).length) {
      $('#' + tid).remove();
    }
  });
});
```

Explicando:
Eu armazeno a `tr` que você selecionou em uma variável.Quando eu clicar no botão de delete ele remove a `tr` selecionada, para remover mais de 1 apenas crie um array, coloque cada 1 dos selecionados dentro do array e no clique do delete faça um `for` percorrendo esse array.
Ou então para remover direto ao clicar na tr, use esse exemplo de um gringo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553768/remove-table-row-after-clicking-table-row-delete-button

Comment: Esta certo, meu código esta bem parecido com a versão que gringo respondeu com puro JS. Estou utilizando classes e métodos...

Comment: A questão é que quando eu deleto e adiciono outro, ele busca dentro de um array vários elementos <tr> e coloca no dom, se eu não deletar do array ele vai adicionar novamente...

Comment: Entendi sua duvida... Bom, vc já pensou em colocar um contador dentro da tr que siga junto o array? (coloque dentro do id, por exemplo). Assim, ao selecionar a tr vc vai ter esse valor e então vc pode remover usando o array.splice(array, var_com_posicao_da_tr)

Comment: Exemplo: <tr><td id='0'>item1</td></tr> <tr><td id='1'>item1</td></tr>e então pega o td.id

Comment: A idéia é valida!!

Answer (score 0):

para obter o indice, você pode usar um `indexOf` sobre o o `children`.

```js
var btsApagar = document.querySelectorAll(".apagar");
var onApagarClick = function (evt) {
  var linha = this.parentElement.parentElement;
  var nodes = [].slice.call(linha.parentElement.children, 0);
  var index = nodes.indexOf(linha);
  console.log(index);
};

[].forEach.call(btsApagar, function (apagar, indice) {
  apagar.addEventListener("click", onApagarClick);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Coluna 01</th>
      <th>Coluna 02</th>
      <th>Ações</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Valor 1.1</td>
      <td>Valor 1.2</td>
      <td><input class="apagar" type="button" value="Apagar" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Valor 2.1</td>
      <td>Valor 2.2</td>
      <td><input class="apagar" type="button" value="Apagar" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Valor 3.1</td>
      <td>Valor 3.2</td>
      <td><input class="apagar" type="button" value="Apagar" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

porém pode vir a ser interessante usar alguma blibioteca para lhe ajudar a manter a DOM e o array sincronizados.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#tabela',
  data: {
    lista: [
      { valor1: "Valor 1.1", valor2: "Valor 1.2" },
      { valor1: "Valor 2.1", valor2: "Valor 2.2" },
      { valor1: "Valor 3.1", valor2: "Valor 3.2" },
      { valor1: "Valor 4.1", valor2: "Valor 4.2" },
      { valor1: "Valor 5.1", valor2: "Valor 5.2" },
      { valor1: "Valor 6.1", valor2: "Valor 6.2" },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    apagar: function (item) {
      var index = this.lista.indexOf(item);
      this.lista.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(index);
    } 
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
<table id="tabela">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Coluna 01</th>
      <th>Coluna 02</th>
      <th>Ações</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="item in lista">
      <td>{{item.valor1}}</td>
      <td>{{item.valor2}}</td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Apagar" v-on:click="apagar(item)" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```